# What does .. means in dart language?

Tags: flutter, dart

What does `..` mean in dart language in flutter projects?

consider following examples:

```cpp
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    vsync: this
  )..repeat();
// ^^ here
```

### NOTE:

I found that there is no reference to cascade operator in the stack overflow, so I added the question and answer to stack itself may be helpful for posterity.

Comment: I found that there is no reference to cascade operator, so I added the question and answer to stack itself may be helpful for prosperity.

Comment: From your question, the operator means invoking the method after creating the AnimationController instance,
which is equal to _controller.repeat()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called cascade operator, which can be read about in [official doc](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#cascades)

In simple form, it says that invoke that method, but instead of returning the return value of method return the reference for the object (class), it is invoked on.

Here although `repeat` is going to run on `AnimationController` it will return the `AnimationController` reference to be stored in `_controller`. It allows to access and invoke another method of `AnimationController` in other parts that got access to `_controller`

Answer (score 1):

Its called cascade operator

For Example, You can use cascade operator like this, It improves readability

```
class User {
  
  double? id;
  
  String? name;

  void printName(){
    print(name ?? 'Name is Null');
  }
  
}

 // Instead of this

  User user = User();
  user.id = 5;
  user.name = 'Maverick';
  user.printName();
  
 // Using Cascade operator

  User user2 = User();
  user2
    ..id = 6
    ..name = 'Kenny'
    ..printName();


  // Another Example using cascade operator

  User user3 = User()..id = 7
                     ..name = 'Roger'
                     ..printName();
```